# How to apply a Kalman Filter to smooth GPS data?

Tags: r, gps, smoothing, kalman-filter

for a research I'm trying to `remove outliers` in `GPS tracks`. I've found in the Internet that a `Kalman Filter` could perform this data cleaning. The main problem is that I can't understand how to implement it in `R` (this is the constraint).

I've found several packages that perform a Kalman Filter such as:

- dlm
- KFAS

Every package requires some information that I don't understand because of the poor package documentation.

An example of my datas are the following:

```
Dev.Id         Time            Lat        Long      High  Direction Velocity  Accuracy
55576   01-01-2019 03:00:22 45.91572    9.262200    721   0         0         1
55576   01-01-2019 03:00:30 45.91587    9.262300    725   0         0         1 
55576   01-01-2019 03:00:36 45.91595    9.262300    723   0         0         1 
55576   01-01-2019 03:00:54 45.91592    9.262366    730   0         0         1
```

The `Direction`, the `Velocity` and the `Accuracy` will assume values different from `0` and `1`. Is anyone that could explain me how to perform a `Kalman Filter` on these data?

Comment: Have you had any success with this? I have a similar problem.